# Use system() to call executable in a changing directory

Tags: c++, regex, windows, cmd, system

I am writing a simple C++ helpertool for a popular game (League of Legends), targeted at windows users.

I wish to allow the user to auto restart games which crash. This can be done by starting 'leagueoflegends.exe'. I want to autodetect the location of the executable and this is where I have issues.

The exe is located at:
*GAME_FOLDER*\RADS\solutions\lol_game_client_sln\releases\x.x.x.xx\leagueoflegends.exe

I use a registry entry to get the game folder, ie: C:\leagueoflegends\

However there is a folder that changed with every update in the form of x.x.x.xx where the x are digits (numbers) reflecting the versions. There is always 1 folder in the releases folder.

I figured I need to use REGEXP but I didn't have much luck.
This is the regexp I made:

```
^[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]$
```

This is what I used to get the name of the dir using cmd

```
dir /B | findstr /R " ^[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]$"
```

However I cant seem to be able to run the executable no matter what I do. Its not like linux where I can manipulate filters and pipes. Any help with a one liner to run the exe or methods of obtaining the folder name (without using a system call?) would be appreciated. Once I can get the folder name in a variable then it becomes easy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using C++, there is boost stuff for directory searching, otherwise use windows API (`FindFirstFile`) or C API (`opendir`) to do so. Especially if there is only one directory to find.

Comment: Yes C++ and I have boost included in this project (using it to read ini configuration file). And the only folder (by default unless user messes with it) is one folder in that format.  So you think opendir is better to use in this case, do you have example code for it?

Comment: I would say that `boost::filesystem` is your best bet then, and you would probably want [directory_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_iterator). If there is only one folder, you should not need to do any parsing, right? You just need to know what it is so you can build the full path. Sorry, but I don't have any sample code at this time.

Comment: I am away from my desktop but I will give it a shot later. Yes just need to detect the folder name to build the full path. However if there is more than 1 folder (user has gone into his files and made  backup, etc, highly unlikely but still), does it give me the first folder? I will be checking if the full path is the .exe in question later so if it still returns the first folder if there are multiple folders, that would be good.

Comment: Basically it will let you iterate over *all* folders in a location, so you can still check to see if you have a match with what you are looking for, just in case.